# Can model comparison be performed on a single dummy variable of a 3-level categorical predictor?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, model-comparison

Let's say I have some observations, *Y*, that I want to regress using a model containing two predictors, *X* and *W*. If I'm interested in whether adding *X* to the model improves it, according to some criterion, I can simply perform a nested model comparison:

full: *Y ~ 1 + X + W*

nested: *Y ~ 1 + W*

In my case, *X* is a categorical variable with 3 levels. Let's call those levels *a*, *b*, and *c*. This means that underlyingly, *X* is represented by two 'dummy' variables: *X<sub>1</sub>*, *X<sub>2</sub>*.

I am specifically interested in whether the difference between *a* on one hand, and *b,c* on the other, explains some of the variance in the data. My question is: Does the following make sense?

1. I use a Helmert coding scheme to recode *X*, like so: *X<sub>1</sub>(a) = 2/3, X<sub>1</sub>(b) = X<sub>1</sub>(c) = -1/3*. And *X<sub>2</sub>(a) = 0, X<sub>2</sub>(b) = 1/2, X<sub>2</sub>(c) = -1/2*. My understanding is that *X<sub>1</sub>* now codes for the contrast between *a* and *b,c*.
2. I compare the following two nested models:

full: *Y ~ 1 + X<sub>1</sub> + X<sub>2</sub> + W*

nested: *Y ~ 1 + X<sub>2</sub> + W*

I couldn't really find anything in the literature that directly addresses this question. If the above is not a licit move, what would be a good way of answering the specific question about the contrast between *a* versus *b,c*? Is the only answer to do the model comparison using *X* as a whole, then perform some sort of post-hoc test, provided *X*'s contribution is significant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If each observation in your data-set only belongs to one level of the categorical variable `X`, then to me it doesn't make sense to break it down like you have described. You have a few options. You can fit the model, and then run post-hoc comparisons, or, if you are interested in knowing if `a` is different from `b` and/or `c`, you can make `a` the reference level. Then a standard regression output will tell you if either (or both) `b` and `c` are different from `a`.

If what you really want to know is if observations in category `a` are different from those that are not `a`, you can also re-code it as a binary variable grouping `b` and `c` together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm interested in knowing whether *a* is different from both *b* and *c*. I thought about coding it as a binary variable, but I wanted a way to test whether the difference along *X* is above and beyond any potential difference between *b* and *c*.
Re: standard regression, this is what I initially tried to do, but because I have other predictors (*W*), I wanted to use model comparison to avoid any issues of credit assignment...